# Site scrolling doesn't work with Chrome SmoothScroll

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, smooth-scrolling

So a friend of mine asked me if I knew why one of his old sites (made in 2014) wasn't working anymore. Googling a bit, I found out it's because of Chrome 61 version implemented the smooth scroll by default and if u try to load a script instead, it will break the browser behaviour.

On his site, I found he's using this script: https://github.com/themicon/smoothscroll/blob/master/smoothscroll.js

He has a menu with some buttons, each of them has a line of code that looks like this:

```
<a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">ABOUT US</a>
```

And it should bring to a line of code that looks like this:

```
<section id="about">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
         </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

The site still works perfectly with Firefox and other browser, so I don't know honestly would I would need to change, I tryed to search for an updated version of the script where maybe the author fixed the issue and found this:

https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites/blob/master/SmoothScroll.js

As you notice, the script hasn't been updated for quite long time, indeed even the latest version is prior to the Chrome 61 version update so I doubt that would solve the problem.

On the very end of site, these are the scripts loaded:

> ```
>   <!-- Bootstrap --> 
>   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
>   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
>   <!-- Animation --> 
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animation/jquery.appear.js"></script>        
>   <!-- AJAX Contact Form -->          
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact/contact-form.js"></script>
>   <!-- Lightbox --> 
>   <script src="lightbox/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>       
>   <!-- Isotope -->     
>   <script src="js/isotope/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="js/isotope/custom-isotope.js"></script>
>   <!-- Slider Revolution 4.x Scripts -->
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js"></script>
>   <script>
>      var revapi;
>
>           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
>
>                  revapi = jQuery('.tp-banner').revolution(
>                   {
>                           delay:9000,
>                           startwidth:1170,
>                           startheight:500,
>                           fullScreen:"on",
>                           forceFullWidth:"on",
>                           minFullScreenHeight:"320",
>                           videoJsPath:"rs-plugin/videojs/"
>                   });
>
>           }); //ready
>   </script>
>   <!-- Custom -->
>   <script src="js/custom.js"></script> 
>   <!-- Parallex -->
>   <script src="js/parallex/script.js"></script> 
>   <!-- ScrollTo -->
>   <script src="js/nav/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script> 
>   <script src="js/nav/jquery.nav.js"></script> 
>   <!-- Sticky -->
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sticky/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
>   <!-- Donut Chart --> 
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/progress-bars/jquery.donutchart.js"></script> 
>   <script>
>      $("#donutchart1").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart2").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart3").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart4").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart5").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart6").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart7").donutchart("animate");
>      $("#donutchart8").donutchart("animate");         
>   </script>        
>   <!-- Owl Carousel --> 
>   <script src="owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
>   <!-- SmoothScroll --> 
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
>   <!-- Retina --> 
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina/retina.js"></script>
>     <!-- FitVids -->
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
> ```